# Scraping a site with java regex

Tags: java, regex, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I would love to scrape the titles of the top 250 movies (https://www.imdb.com/chart/top/) for educational purposes.

I have tried a lot of things but I messed up at the end every time. Could you please help me scrape the titles with Java and regex?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class scraping {

    public static void main (String args[]) {
        try {
            URL URL1=new URL("https://www.imdb.com/chart/top/");

            URLConnection URL1c=URL1.openConnection();
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new 
            InputStreamReader(URL1c.getInputStream(),"ISO8859_7"));

            String line;int lineCount=0;

            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<td\\s+class=\"titleColumn\"[^>]*>"+ ".*?</a>");
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(br.readLine());

            while(matcher.find()){
                System.out.println(matcher.group());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception: " + e.getClass() + ", Details: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Use Jsoup and your life should get easier.

Comment: u can use selenium and scape the xml

Comment: Your readLine just return an empty string at the moment ^^

Comment: @azro could you please help me with that? Cause my brain will explode at this time after so many tries. How can I print the content of td class=titleColumn ?

Comment: Check out https://regex101.com/r/XfiaB7/1 if you're adamant on making it work in regex

Comment: There are better ways to scrape the website, like using an API, but if you want to use regex, try: title=".*"\s>(.*)\s?<\/a> to get the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Parsing Mode

To parse an XML or HTML content, a dedicated parser will always be easier than a regex, for HTML in Java there is `Jsoup`, you'll get your films very easily :

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.imdb.com/chart/top/").get();
Elements films = doc.select("td.titleColumn");
for (Element film : films) {
    System.out.println(film);
}

<td class="titleColumn"> 1. <a href="/title/tt0111161/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&amp;pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&amp;pf_rd_r=5BDHP4VZE8EGSEZC4ZSF&amp;pf_rd_s=center-1&amp;pf_rd_t=15506&amp;pf_rd_i=top&amp;ref_=chttp_tt_1" title="Frank Darabont (dir.), Tim Robbins, Morgan Freeman">Les évadés</a> <span class="secondaryInfo">(1994)</span> </td>
<td class="titleColumn"> 2. <a href="/title/tt0068646/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&amp;pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&amp;pf_rd_r=5BDHP4VZE8EGSEZC4ZSF&amp;pf_rd_s=center-1&amp;pf_rd_t=15506&amp;pf_rd_i=top&amp;ref_=chttp_tt_2" title="Francis Ford Coppola (dir.), Marlon Brando, Al Pacino">Le parrain</a> <span class="secondaryInfo">(1972)</span> </td>
```

To get the content only  :

```
for (Element film : films) {
    System.out.println(film.getElementsByTag("a").text());
}

Les évadés
Le parrain
Le parrain, 2ème partie
```

---

## Regex Mode

You were not reading the whole content of the website, also it's XML type so all is not on the same line, you can't find the beginning and the end of the balise on the same line, you may read all, and then use the regex, it gives something like this :

```
URL url = new URL("https://www.imdb.com/chart/top/");
InputStream is = url.openStream();

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is))) {
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line);
    }
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    throw new MalformedURLException("URL is malformed!!");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    throw new IOException();
}

// Full line
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<td class=\"titleColumn\">.*?</td>");
String content = sb.toString();
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(content);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}

// Title only
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<td class=\"titleColumn\">.+?<a href=.+?>(.+?)</a>.+?</td>");
String content = sb.toString();
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(content);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your code. At the Regex mode, I have a problem with the results. I wanna make a list with the names only without the tags. How can I isolate the titles from HTML tags? Thank you again really much.

Answer (score 0):

As the [existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59459645/3764965) says, the Jsoup or other HTML parser should be used for sake of correctness.

I only complete your current solution if you want to use a similar approach for a more reasonable use-case. It cannot work, because you read only the first line from the buffer:

```
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(br.readLine);
```

Also the Regex pattern is wrong, because your solution seems is built to read 1 line-by-line and test that only line agasint the Regex. The source of the website shows that the content of the table row is spread across multiple lines.

The solution based on reading 1 line should use much simpler [Regex](https://regex101.com/r/oBUnbQ/1) (I am sorry, the example contains movie namess in my native language):

```
\" ?>([^<]+)<\/a>
```

An example of working code is:

```
try {
    URL URL1=new URL("https://www.imdb.com/chart/top/");

    URLConnection URL1c=URL1.openConnection();
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new
    InputStreamReader(URL1c.getInputStream(),"ISO8859_7"));

    String line;int lineCount=0;

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\" ?>([^<]+)<\\/a>"); // Compiled once

    br.lines()                       // Stream<String>
      .map(pattern::matcher)         // Stream<Matcher> 
      .filter(Matcher::find)         // Stream<Matcher> .. if Regex matches
      .limit(250)                    // Stream<Matcher> .. to avoid possible mess below
      .map(m -> m.group(1))          // String<String>  .. captured movie name
      .forEach(System.out::println); // Printed out

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception: " + e.getClass() + ", Details: " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

Note the following:

1. Regex is **not** suitable for this. Use a library built for this use-case.
2. My solution is an working example, but the performance is poor (Stream API, Regex pattern matching of *each* line)...
3. Solution like this doesn't guarantee a possible mess. The Regex *can* captrue more than intended.
4. The website content, CSS class names etc. might change in the future.